# Downloading a file using DropBox API (with DropNet)

Tags: c#, .net, dropbox, dropnet

I'm doing a dropbox app. It uses DropNet, the problem is when I try to download a file from the App's folder, it returns the json:

> {"error": "Given request root of "dropbox" but app is an App Folder app."}

That's my code:

```
   static void DownloadFile(string token, string secret) {
        var client = new DropNetClient(apikey, apisecret, token, secret);

        client.GetFileAsync("/Apps/MY_APP/test.txt",
            (response) => {
                var content = GetString(response.RawBytes);
                Console.WriteLine(content);
            },
            (error) => {
                Console.WriteLine(error.ToString() + " error downloading");
            });
    }
```

The file exists on this path. I've tried with "test.txt", "/test.txt" and etc.
I guess it's some generic problem, but still? Also the app has rights only in its folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property on your instance of DropNetClient called `UseSandbox` this changes the requests to use the app folder mode instead of root folder.